# Efficient, clean javascript? Javascript learning resources?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a big fan of keeping my code clean and tidy, I am very much a beginner to javascript however. I was wondering if the following code could be written better/cleaner:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$('.clickMe').click(function() {
$('.refine_icon').toggleClass("opened");
$('.advancedSearch').slideToggle(400);
$(this).text($(this).text() == 'More search options' ? 'Fewer search options' : 'More search options');      
return false;
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code looks fine, and for something simple can't be improved a great deal. I would use proper indenting though:

```
$('.clickMe').click(function() {
    $('.refine_icon').toggleClass("opened");
    $('.advancedSearch').slideToggle(400);
    $(this).text($(this).text() == 'More search options' ? 'Fewer search options' : 'More search options');      
    return false;
});
```

One thing you could do is replace `return false;` with jQuery's `preventDefault()`. Returning `false` not only stops the default behaviour of the browser, but prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree. Usually this isn't a problem, but if you're interested in writing code that has minimal side effects, then this is the way to go:

```
$('.clickMe').click(function (e) { // Notice the e
    e.preventDefault();
    // Rest of your code
});
```

[jQuery Fundamentals](http://jqfundamentals.com/book/index.html) is a comprehensive online book that explains the basics of both JavaScript and jQuery (with a focus on jQuery though).